# Equivalent turtlesim/Pose and geometry_msgs/Pose

Tags: ros, pose, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a question about the *Pose* message. There art two different *Pose* :

- geometry_msgs/Pose.msg 
  Point position
  Quaternion orientation
- turtlesim/Pose.msg 
   float32 x 
   float32 y 
   float32 theta  
   float32 linear_velocity 
   float32 angular_velocity

I want to know what is the equivalent of turtlesim pose.theta in the geometry pose :

- pose.orientation.z ?
- pose.orientation.w ?
- yaw from *euler_from_quaternion(pose.orientation.x, pose.orientation.y, pose.orientation.z, pose.orientation.w)* ?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327256/equivalent-turtlesim/pose-and-geometry_msgs/pose/) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no 1 to 1 mapping between `turtlesim pose.theta` and any of the values in `geometry_msgs/Pose`. The turtlesim pose is a 2D pose so it expresses orientation as a single angle in radians, but `geometry_msgs/Pose` is a 3D pose so it expresses rotation as a Quaternion (4D unit vector).

If you need to create a `geometry_msgs/Pose` from a `turtlesim/Pose` message then you can use the `tf2::Quaternion.setRPY( Roll, Pitch, Yaw )` method and set Roll and Pitch to zero. This will create the quaternion and do all the complicated maths for you.

Here is some background on [rotation quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) if you want to learn about the theory.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

If it is safe to assume that your robot will always be upright on a level surface then it will be safe to use the euler_from_quaternion method to calculate the roll, pitch and yaw of the pose and then to take the yaw value and use that. It should be noted that the behaviour of this approach will be strange and incorrect if the pose messages are not level!

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-06-28**:
I am trying to write a *Go to Goal* code for my robot based on [turtlesim Go to Goal tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials/Go%20to%20Goal). Howerver, how I suscribe to my robot's pose is different than for the turtlesim one.  I suscribed to my odom topic and use the pose of my odom message.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-28**:
To clarify you need to convert a `geometry_msgs/Pose` into a `turtlesim/Pose` message?

**Comment by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on 2019-07-01**:
Yes. In the tutorial, they use the `turtlesim/Pose.theta` but I don't know to what it corresponds in the `geometry_msgs/Pose`.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-02**:
I've updated me answer for you now.